# How to implement pinch zoom

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone8 xaml c# application, I need to implement pinch zoom in my reader page. Any help?

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Semantic_Zoom_in_Windows_Phone_8

Answer (score 0):

you could follow this msdn tutorial

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp7/start/gestures-flick-pan-and-stretch

And

The Windows Phone emulator only supports multitouch gestures with a multitouch device. You would have to have a screen, or touchpad to work with it. Also, there has been comments about using two mice and there is a project on codeplex http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com for it.